# Getting URL in status-bar immediately on hovering over a link

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to configure Google Chrome so that when I hover over a link I can see the target URL in the status-bar immediately (i.e. without having to wait before the URL getting entirely displayed)?

I use the latest version of Google Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.153 m) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Unless your machine is incredibly slow, it does appear immediately.

Comment: @MattVoboril Hmm it is neither immediate on my laptop (i7) nor on my Alienware 6-physical-core desktop. Gif added. I would have said at worse I have some extension slowning Chrome down, but same issue in incognito.

Comment: So, really, you're saying that transitions are too slow, not that showing the status bar takes a second or two (since it takes less than a second)? I don't understand why you are asking.

Comment: @MattVoboril I didn't time it precisely, just meant the URL getting does not get entirely displayed immediately...

Comment: But why does it matter? Is it not fast enough that you can see it if you need to? I'm trying to see this from your perspective. The slowing is probably from background apps running that affect chrome's speed, which would include extensions if you leave your non-incognito window open, and other applications that are running on your computer. Considering how many extensions I can see in that gif, at least the bottoms of them, try uninstalling them instead of trying to think of incognito as a faster way to run Chrome.

Comment: @MattVoboril The faster the full URL get displayed, the better. Besides avoiding some waiting time, I use a control the mouse cursor with my head and it's annoying having to hover on a small zone for a long time (vs. a traditional computer mouse where not moving is straightforward).

Comment: @MattVoboril Regarding the number of extensions, beyond incognito I have the same waiting time with Canary.

Comment: Do you need to see it for security purposes, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @MattVoboril As an additional information for me to know whether it is worth to click on the link (which sometime includes security reason).  Pretty much the same reasons why people want to have the full URL in the status-bar I guess.

Comment: Try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-revealer/nphhadgebjlmcfleikmiedhohdfbfoin?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Answer (score 1):

That always happened to Chrome, since the firsts versions of the program, as I remember, and it seems it's not possible to modify the delay time to show the URL in the status bar, I have looked through the Experiments section of Chrome (chrome://flags) and found no function which allows you to do that.

You can switch to a browser which shows quickly the URL in the status bar, such as Opera.