# How do I force Chrome to display the URL at the bottom when you hover over a link?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

For some reason, the updated Chrome is not showing the URL at the bottom for links. Is there a way to force the display of the URL when you hover over a link in Chrome? This question did not help: [Getting URL in status-bar immediately on hovering over a link](https://superuser.com/questions/778533/getting-url-in-status-bar-immediately-on-hovering-over-a-link).

Version 44.0.2403.89 m

Notice the underlined link in the title, but no URL showing.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Works for me: Version 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit) on Linux. Maybe some extension is to blame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Chrome is working. Version 45.0.2454.85 m